# Get ranged string from text file without opening file with stringWithContentsOfFile

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsrange

I'm trying read text from text file.
I used stringWithContentsOfFile to do this.

```
pathName        = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sample ofType:@"txt"];
entireContent   = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
entireChapter   = [entireContent substringWithRange:sourceRange];
```

Have any of you got another way to get string fast?

Comment: Are you looking for an asynchronous solution?

Comment: Is there a way to open a file and move fp to get a ranged string? Or shoud i implement one?

Comment: Getting whole string every time Takes too long time.

Comment: solutions  like fopen -> fseek -> fread.

Comment: but not posix way and encoding-safe way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use NSFileHandle.

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandler = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
[fileHandler seekToFileOffset:10];
NSData *data = [fileHandler readDataOfLength:10];
[fileHandler closeFile];
```

you can try this. then you can convert nsdata to string.